# Counting Squarefree Integers $i \le n$ Coprime to the First $k$ Primes

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, computer-science, mobius-function

The number of positive squarefree integers $i \le n$ is given by: $$C(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}\mu(k)\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k^{2}}\right\rfloor.$$
The number of positive integers $i\le n$ coprime to the first $k$ prime numbers admits the recurrence relation: $$\phi(n, k) = \lfloor n / p_k \rfloor - \phi(\lfloor n/p_k \rfloor, k-1) + \phi(n, k-1)$$

But I haven't managed to find any literature regarding the subject of numbers that are both squarefree **AND** coprime to the first $k$ prime numbers, with the exception of odd/even such integers ($k=1, p = 2$). Let $P_k = p_1\cdot p_2 \cdot...\cdot p_k$ be the primorial of the first $k$ primes. If we define $$f(n,k) = \sum_{i = 1 \atop gcd(i,P_k)=1}^{n}|\mu(i)|$$

to be the count of squarefree integers coprime to the first $k$ primes, then does this formula admit any elegant representations? Is there any way to efficiently exactly count (not an approximation) such numbers mathematically or at least compute this count efficiently?

Comment: Is your formula for $\phi(n,k)$ missing some floor functions.  Could you please enter those in or provide link that derives the formulas?

Comment: yes, will add them, thank you

Comment: $$\sum_{n\le x, \gcd(n,m)=1} |\mu(n)| = 
\sum_{d| m} \mu(d) \sum_{n\le x/d} |\mu(dn)|=\sum_{d\in A_m} \lambda(d)\sum_{n\le x/d}|\mu(n)|$$ where $A_m$ are the integers whose every prime factors divide $m$.

Comment: @reuns Hey, I tried the formula, but it doesn't agree with a brute-force calculation. I interpreted $\lambda (d)$ as Carmichael function. Calculating $f(10,2)$ for example gives $24$ instead of $3$. Are you sure it is correct?

Answer (score 2):

To approach your problem, I would just write down your formula in terms of images and inverse images of the involved functions.

So take $|\mu|(n)$ to be the absolute value of $\mu(n)$ for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Then:

$$
f(n,k) = \sum_{a=1}^n|\mu|(a \in \gcd^{-1}( p_1\cdots p_k,\cdot)(1))
$$

Where, if you look at $\gcd(p_1\cdots p_k, n) = g(n)$ as a multiplicative function, then we're interested in $\ker g$.

Thus $f(n,k) = |[1,..,n]\cap \ker |\mu| \cap \ker g|$,

$|\mu|$ also being a multiplicative function.

This is about as elegant a formula that I can come up with.

Note that $\ker g$ here is defined here as $\ker g = \{ n \in \Bbb{N}: g(n) = 1\}$, but the set **$\ker |\mu|, \ker g$ are not monoids.**  They do however satisfy: if $a, b \in \ker g: \gcd(a,b) = 1 \implies ab \in \ker g$.

---

This means that the limit supremum exists for $a_n = f(n,k)/n$, i.e. $\lim\sup_{n \to \infty} a_n = \overline{d}(A)$, where $A = \ker g \cap \ker |\mu|$.

See [natural density examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).  Since the bound is from above, we must have:
$\overline{d}(A) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{|[1..n] \cap \ker |\mu||}{n} = 6/\pi^2$.

And $\underline{d}(A) \geq 0$.

---

I thought that I'd mention natural density because the problem naturally takes that form (just add a denominator $n$ and take lim sup/inf).

---

We also have a related formula:

$$\ker |\mu| \cap \ker g = \ker (|\mu| \cdot g) = \{ n \in \Bbb{N} : |\mu(n)|g(n) = 1 \}$$, where $|\mu| \cdot g$ is also a multiplicative function, i.e. for all $a,b \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, you have that $|\mu|(ab)g(ab) = (|\mu|(a)g(a))(|\mu|(b)g(b))$.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. Some of the math is too complex for me, so I will have to do some extra reading. Is the representation that you mentioned for $f(n,k)$ computable?

Comment: @MCFromScratch $\mu$ is computable because factoring is, but intersecting with the kernel of its absolute value, not sure.  I shortened the post a bit by taking out the part about binary operations applied to sets elementwise.

Comment: For small values of $n$ you can test whether $\gcd(p_1 \cdots p_k, n) = 1$ and $|\mu(n)| = 1$.   Since $n$ is small you can factor it quickly enough.

Comment: @MCFromScratch see bolded part I added.  $\ker g, \ker |\mu|$ are not monoids, but if $a, b \in \ker g$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $ab \in \ker g$.